# How to hide / unhide columns in bootstrap data table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have this simple bootstrap data table code below

```
var dataTablesFirstBS = $('#dataTables-FIrstSample').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    info: true,
    retrieve: true,
    destroy: true,
    search: true,
    stateSave: true,
    center: true,
    order: [[1, "asc"]],
    lengthMenu: [[50, 100, 200, -1], [50, 100, 200, "All"]],
    ajax: { "url": "/BS/GetFirstDataTable" },
    columns:
    [
        { data: "BSId", title: "ID", visible: true },
        { data: "Name", title: "Name", align: "center", sortable: false },
        { data: "LName", title: "L Name", align: "center", searchable: false }
    ]
});
```

as you can see I have 3 columns only. I am trying to make visible the `BSId`. I try to use `hidden: false` but its not working. Is there a problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

On the [Datatables hidden columns page](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html) it looks like `visible` defaults to true.

Shouldn't you say: `"visible": false` for columns you want to hide?

Comment: For now I want to show the column for BSId because it is hidden. I already try `visible: false / true` or `hidden: false / true` but nothing happen. but in your suggestion gonna try it.